# Angular2: Duplicate identifier and can not find module

Tags: typescript, angular, typescript1.6, typescript-typings, tsconfig

My angular project was working fine, when im including new ts file and copy and pasted file content from other project im getting duplicate identifier under modules name in the import statement and can not file module

Comment: Thats because you are using Typescript. Moreover,  In angular project, you must have mentioned to look for all .ts files in app folder. Typescript is very strict and typescript transpiler will check the things you do and i think it encounters duplicate entities. So i guess you are facing such issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "filesGlob" entry in your `tsconfig.json` file to exclude unnecessary files. For example :

```
"filesGlob": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./test/**/*.ts",
    "!./node_modules/**/*.ts",
    "typings/browser.d.ts"
  ]
```

`!`means you are excluding the node_modules. Let me know if it works. Or you have to update questions with more details